# Сохранение изменений в БД через DataGridView

Tags: c#, ms-access

Есть база данных, сделанная в MS Access, есть программа, которая должна по идее с данными в БД работать, но  она не работает. По нажатию кнопки открывается окно с текстовыми полями, в которые вбиваются данные в таблице, в DataGridView новые данные отображаются но БД не обновляется. С удалением то же самое.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataBase
{
    public partial class Rooms : Form
    {
        public Rooms()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "accessDataSet.Rooms". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.roomsTableAdapter.Fill(this.accessDataSet.Rooms);

        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddRoom f = new AddRoom();  

            if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // отобразить форму
            {
                string Number, Type;

                Number = f.textBox1.Text;
                Type = f.comboBox1.Text;

                this.roomsTableAdapter.Insert(Number, Type);
                this.roomsTableAdapter.Fill(this.accessDataSet.Rooms);


            }
            }

        private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DelRoom d = new DelRoom();

            int RoomID;
            String Number, Type;
            int index;

            index = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

            RoomID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, index].Value);
            Number = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[1, index].Value);
            Type = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[2, index].Value);

            d.label2.Text = Number + "" + Type;

            if (d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                roomsTableAdapter.Delete(RoomID, Number, Type);
                this.roomsTableAdapter.Fill(this.accessDataSet.Rooms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, через какой API происходит подключение? ADO? ODBC? DAO?

Answer (score 0):

По книгам должно быть так

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Name, Age) VALUES('Tim', 34)";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();//вставка

 command.CommandText = "Delete from Users where USers.ID =" idUser;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();//удаление
```

У Вас команды есть, а выполнение их скорее всего нет...